# AngularJS $routeProvider routing differently by page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

My build process concatenates all JS, so without any hacking, is there a way to specify a `$routerProvider` should only be used on a single page, or overwrite the `$routeProvider` to respond with page appropriate routes?

I have this:

`/app/page1#/many-things-go-here`

and `/app/page2#/many-things-go-here`

I want the handling of these routes to be separate. How do I do that?

Comment: When you say pages, you mean different Single-Page-Applications right? So I imagine they each create a new instance of the Angular app, but you only want the $routeProvider to 'work' on one of those instances. Is that more or less correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT -- original answer below
The easiest way to do it would be to add a script block to each page to define a module constant that you then check in the config section where you are configuring routeProvider.

Example:

```
// page1.html
angular.module('app').constant('SHOULD_USE_ROUTE_PROVIDER', false);

// page2.html
angular.module('app').constant('SHOULD_USE_ROUTE_PROVIDER', true);

// module config section
angular.module('app').config(function(..., SHOULD_USE_ROUTE_PROVIDER) {
   ...
   if (SHOULD_USE_ROUTE_PROVIDER) {
      // configure it here
   }
   ...
});
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The angular way would be to add a provider (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) that allows you to configure a flag to determine if the routerProvider should be used... assuming you create a RoutingProvider with a shouldUseRouterProvider property, then in your routes file that has the routerProvider specific logic, you can inject the provider and check:

```
// inject RouterProvider

if (RouterProvider.shouldUseRouterProvider) {
    ... routerProvider configuration
}
```

If  you use this method, then in your pages, just add a script block with a module.config section that sets up the configuration for that page like:

```
angular.module('app').config(['RouterProvider', function(RouterProvider) {
    RouterProvider.shouldUseRouterProvider = false;
}]);
```

---

The hacky way of doing it would be to set a global variable in the script block of each page and check for it in the angular related code that sets up the routerProvider.